# Error scraping friend list from Twitter user w/ api.lookup_users: Too many terms specified in query

Tags: python, tweepy

The code below was provided to another user who was scraping the "friends" (not followers) list of a specific Twitter user. For some reason, I get an error when using "api.lookup_users". The error states "Too many terms specified in query". Ideally, I would like to scrape the followers and output a csv with the screen names (not ids). I would like their descriptions as well, but can do this in a separate step unless there is a suggestion for pulling both pieces of information. Below is the code that I am using:

```
import time
import tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="").pages():
    ids.extend(page)
    time.sleep(60)

print(len(ids))

users = api.lookup_users(user_ids=ids) #iterates through the list of         users and prints them
for u in users:
    print(u.screen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error you get, it seems that you are putting too many ids at once in the api.lookup_users request. Try splitting you list of ids in smaller parts and make a request for each part.

```
import time
import tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="").pages():
    ids.extend(page)
    time.sleep(60)

print(len(ids))

idChunks = [ids[i:i + 300] for i in range(0, len(ids), 300)]
users = []
for idChunk in idChunks:
   try:
       users.append(api.lookup_users(user_ids=idChunk))
   except tweepy.error.RateLimitError:
       print("RATE EXCEDED. SLEEPING FOR 16 MINUTES")
       time.sleep(16*60)
       users.append(api.lookup_users(user_ids=idChunk))

for u in users:
    print(u.screen_name)
    print(u.description)
```

This code has not been tested, and does not writes the CSV, but it should help you getting past that error you were having. The size of 300 for the chunks is completely arbitrary, adjust it if it is too small (or too big).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I do not believe this is the problem since I came across this error later and the error message is different. I ended up doing this scrape in R. However, I wanted to point out that if one is using tweepy, a command for dealing with the rate limit using your method is as follows: api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

Comment: From my experience with tweepy, I would not advise to solely rely on `wait_on_rate_limit`. I have encountered several RateLimitErrors with this option enabled. You said you had a different error message later? What was it?

Comment: Ok, that is good to know. I ran it on about 130 twitter users and it worked, so hopefully it will be possible to learn why one would still get a rate limit error. The error for the original problem posted above include the language, "Too many terms specified in query", which is different from the errors I get regarding rate limits. The latter includes the language, "Error 88: Rate limit exceeded."